# How to test a method that never returns?

Tags: java, unit-testing

How can I test method behaviour of my class?

```
public class InfiniteWhileLoop {
    public void fun() {
        while (true) {
            // some code to test
        }
    }
}
```

I need to test method `fun` and make sure that it set the field to "xyz". The problem is I get an infinite loop. So I need to run while loop and let it to set the field and after that stop the loop.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need a loop to set the value of a field?

Comment: Can't you just take out the while loop? It's difficult to understand your problem. Right now you just state you have an infinite loop. The solution is to take it out or add a condition.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand the question. You get an infinite loop because you've written `while (true)`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `while(true)` without a break most certainly *will* lead to an infinite loop.  You've got a bug in your code, not your test.

Comment: Maybe there are some callbacks in Mockito? I'm looking for a tool to test that kind of stuff.

Comment: Just extract the content of the `while` loop into a separate method, and test that method. You will need to clarify how you are going to ".... _and after that stop the loop_" as per your question.

Comment: how do you know when to stop the loop?

Comment: I stop it with `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: are any mocks involved? you could then throw an exception to stop the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If another dependency is involved, you could escape with an exception.

Sample using Mockito (could also be achieved with manual faking the dependency)

```
public class Foo
{
    public interface Bar
    {
        void doSomething();
    }

    private Bar bar;
    private int counter = 0;

    public Foo( Bar bar )
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void loop()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            counter++;
            bar.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public int getCounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
public class FooTest
{
    @SuppressWarnings( "serial" )
    private class TestException extends RuntimeException
    {}

    @Test
    public void loop3ShouldIncrementCounterBy3() throws Exception
    {
        Bar bar = mock( Bar.class );
        Foo cut = new Foo( bar );

        doNothing().doNothing().doThrow( new TestException() ).when( bar ).doSomething();

        try
        {
            cut.loop();
        }
        catch ( TestException e )
        {}

        assertThat( cut.getCounter(), is( 3 ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. It does exactly what I expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem. But if you are trying to unit test your method, then you may extract the code you want to test to a different class and then test the new class you created.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score -1):

`while` loops continue until the condition returns false, so `while(true);` never has the capability to determine a `false` value instead of `true`.

You could add a `break;` which will break out of the loop when it is called. Like this:

```
while(true)
{
    String response = testStuff();
    if ("Success".equals(response))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

However, it is usually more clear to put the condition in the `while` loop - it is where people expect the condition to be and it is easier to read. Like so:

```
String response = "Default";
while(!response.equals("Success"))
{
    response = testStuff();
}
```

Lets say you input a command on another thread which changes a variable. The same things apply. Note that it has to be changed on another thread, or within the while loop itself - otherwise the never-ending loop will not allow the code to get anywhere else.

```
static String command = "Continue";
while(command.equals("Continue"))
{
    testStuff();
}

//I input something which changes command to "Stop"
//The while loop will end *AFTER* it's current run through testStuff() - not immediately.
```